# How do i use the Emgu CV _SmoothGausian Method

Tags: c#-4.0, gaussian, emgucv, computer-vision

Im trying to get the OCR sample app to recognise some small text and how I'm doing it is to resize the image. Once I have resized the image it is all 'pixel-ee'

**I want to use the SmothGaussian method to clean it up but I get an error each time I execute the method**

Here is the code:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(openImageFileDialog.FileName);

           using (Image<Gray, byte> gray = image.Convert<Gray, Byte>().Resize(800, 600, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR, true))
           {

               gray.Convert<Gray, Byte>()._SmoothGaussian(4);



              _ocr.Recognize(gray);
              Tesseract.Charactor[] charactors = _ocr.GetCharactors();
              foreach (Tesseract.Charactor c in charactors)
              {
                  image.Draw(c.Region, drawColor, 1);
              }

              imageBox1.Image = image;

              //String text = String.Concat( Array.ConvertAll(charactors, delegate(Tesseract.Charactor t) { return t.Text; }) );
              String text = _ocr.GetText();
              ocrTextBox.Text = text;
           }
```

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: Try this: image =  image.SmoothGaussian(13,13,2,0);

Comment: Why do you try to convert your image to `<Gray, Byte>` when it already is in that format? Not that it will matter, but it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

`_SmoothGaussian` can only handle odd numbers as kernel size so try with 3 or 5 as argument instead.